# Changing port in Apache Traffic Server: Default is 80

Tags: port, reverse-proxy, apache-traffic-server

How can one change the default port in Apache Traffic Server? Default is 80.
I have changed it to one of unreserved port through `proxy.config.socks.http_port`.
It does not seem to be working.
I am sure it must be a very small thing which is missing.

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the default is actually 8080 if you built from the source tree. You are not modifying the correct configuration though, the one you are modifying is for SOCKS support (which is not HTTP). What you are looking for is proxy.config.http.server_ports.

For more details, see https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/reference/configuration/records.config.en.html?#proxy-config-http-server-ports

E.g.

CONFIG proxy.config.http.server_ports STRING 8888

Answer (score 0):

Well, to open ports with numbers under 1024, you must run with `sudo`.